# Setting on() and off() states using hover on buttons with jQuery 1.7

Tags: jquery, button, hover

I currently have my hover states being disabling using the "off()" method. 
I can't seem to get the hover re-enabled with "on()" for the buttons that are not my active link. Any help would greatly appreciated!!

```
$(".datesmenu li").hover(function () {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
            color: "#88bfdc",
            duration: 200,
            easing: "easeOutExpo",
            complete: function () {}
        });
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
            color: "#fff",
            duration: 200,
            easing: "easeOutExpo",
            complete: function () {}
        });
    });

        $(".datesmenu li").click(function(){

                var index = $(this).prevAll().length;

                for (var i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
                   if (i==index){
                        $('#d' + index).stop(true, true).delay(500).fadeIn("fast"), function () {}
                        $(this).off('hover');
                        $(this).css('color', '#88bfdc');
                        //$(this).removeAttr('href');
                    }
                    else{
                        $(".datesmenu li").not(this).css('color', '#fff');
                        $(".datesmenu li").not(this).on('hover', function(event) {event.preventDefault();});                            
                        $('#d' + i).fadeOut("fast");
                        }
                }
    });
```

Idrumgood- I couldn't get your solution to work..I ended up having to use ubind..However, when I use this method I lose the easing to my animation on my rollovers..The color changes but the animation gets removed for some reason??..Let me know if you have a better and cleaner solution, as this was the only way I could get it to work...

```
function init(){

  $(".datesmenu li").mouseenter(hoverOn);
  $(".datesmenu li").mouseleave(hoverOut);
}


$(".datesmenu li").click(function () {

var index = $(this).prevAll().length;

for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    if (i == index) {
        $('#d' + index).stop(true, true).delay(500).fadeIn("fast"), function () {}
        $(this).css('color', '#88bfdc');
        $(this).unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave');
    } else {
        $('#d' + i).hide();
        $(".datesmenu li").not(this).mouseenter(hoverOn);
        $(".datesmenu li").not(this).mouseleave(hoverOut);
        $(".datesmenu li").not(this).css('color', '#fff');

     }
   }
 });

function hoverOn(e) {
$(e.target).stop(true, true).animate({
    color: "#88bfdc",
    duration: 200,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    complete: function () {}
 });
}

  function hoverOut(e) {
  $(e.target).stop(true, true).animate({
    color: "#fff",
    duration: 200,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    complete: function () {}
  });
  }

  init();
```

Comment: Thats because you don't have any code in the `hover` handler which is inside `click` handler.

Answer (score 1):

When you're setting the hover event back on `$(".datesmenu li").not(this).on('hover', function(event) {event.preventDefault();});` you're not telling it to do anything. It won't just put the previously declared hover event back on.

Take your hover events, put them in functions, then attach them as such.

```
function hoverOn(e){
        $(e.target).stop(true, true).animate({
            color: "#88bfdc",
            duration: 200,
            easing: "easeOutExpo",
            complete: function () {}
        });
}

function hoverOut(e){
        $(e.target).stop(true, true).animate({
            color: "#fff",
            duration: 200,
            easing: "easeOutExpo",
            complete: function () {}
        });
}
```

Then when you want to bind it back on:

```
$(".datesmenu li").not(this).on('hover', function(event) {hoverOn(event)}, function(event){hoverOut(event)});
```

Comment: Not sure I'm following so get rid of my hover functions and bind the events "hoverout" and hoverin?

Comment: Technically you're doing your initial hover binding just fine. I put them into functions because you need to reuse them when you bind the hover event again in your click code. The point is that you need to explicitly declare the hover functions again when you rebind it.